# Python class object in array

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to make an array of class objects. When I create the object, it works great:

```
class Complex(object):

    def __init__(self, realpart, imagpart):
        #creates complex number
        self.r = realpart
        self.i = imagpart

    def __str__(self):
        '''Returns complex number as a string'''
        return '(%s + %s j)' % (self.r, self.i) 

a = Complex(1,0)
print a

(1 + 0 j)
```

But when I try to put a in an array, I get an error:

```
arr1 = [a]

[<__ main __.Complex object at 0x5afab0>]
```

Why could this be happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Override `__repr__` as well: `__repr__ = __str__`

Comment: That's not really an error, and, depending on how you want to use this list of objects, may not cause problems for you at all.  It's just a display issue.

Comment: Your title is slightly misleading: you don't pout a class object into the array, but an instance of it.

Answer (score 3):

Because `__repr__` was used instead of `__str__`. Override `__repr__` as Ashwini Chaudhary commented.

```
>>> class Complex(object):
...     def __init__(self, realpart, imagpart):
...         self.r = realpart
...         self.i = imagpart
...     def __str__(self):
...         '''Returns complex number as a string'''
...         return '(%s + %s j)' % (self.r, self.i)
...     __repr__ = __str__ # <-----
...
>>> a = Complex(1,0)
>>> [a]
[(1 + 0 j)]
```

Comment: Note that it may be better to provide a less ambiguous `repr` representation, such as `Complex(1, 0)`. With this implementation, it's difficult to tell exactly what kind of object you're dealing with. It looks like the built-in type, but slightly mangled.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#built-in-types), `print` normally calls `__str__`, so when you printed the object, `__str__` is invoked. But when you print the builtin collections, the `__str__` method of them invoke `__iter__` of the individual elements in it. So, your must implement `__iter__` on your own, or let the default `__repr__` as it is.

If you decide to implement `__repr__` yourself, the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) say,

> If at all possible, this should look like a valid Python expression
>   that could be used to recreate an object with the same value (given an
>   appropriate environment). If this is not possible, a string of the
>   form <...some useful description...> should be returned. The return
>   value must be a string object.

So, if you are implementing it yourself, give as much information as possible, so that the `__repr__` output is unambiguous and useful for debugging.

```
def __str__(self):
    '''Returns complex number as a string'''
    return '< Complex({} + {}j) >'.format(self.r, self.i)
```

You can read more about this, [in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2626364/1903116)